# Is italic correction different in different fonts?

Tags: fonts, spacing, plain-tex, best-practices

I am reading Knuth's *The TeXbook* and in Chapter 4, he talks about italic correction `\/`. He always uses it in the scope of the *preceding* font, for instance:

1. `{\sl slanted\/} words`
2. `{\it italics\/} for`
3. `` `{\bf f\/}’ ``

**Question:** Does it make a difference if I instead write `{\sl slanted}\/ words` for instance?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @PeterWilson I couldn't find any difference, but am not sure if (the handful of) examples I have tried indeed capture the whole behaviour.

Comment: Hm, your question title seems not to fully fit the question you are actually asking. Or maybe I am missing something ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the output trace:

```
\tracingoutput=1
\tracingonline=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen

{\sl f\/} g

{\sl f}\/ g

\bye
```

We get

```
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tensl f
...\kern 1.93521
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm g
```

for the first line and

```
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tensl f
...\kern 1.93521
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
...\tenrm g
```

for the second one.

They're the same: when typesetting takes place, grouping has already been digested and the italic correction command looks at the character that precedes it.